# How to efficiently check if a binary schema is a sub-schema of another binary schema

Tags: c#, string

I have a string consisting of `0`, `1` and `*` (wildcard character) and this is called a binary schema, e.g. `0*10*`.

Suppose I have a list of schemas e.g. `[11010, 0010*, 0*11*, 1*100]`, only `0010*` is sub-schema of `0*10*`.

All schemas being compared are guaranteed to be of same length, though can be set initially in the program.

Edit:
So far, here's the step solution I can think of:

1. find wildcard indices in both schema and compare if one is superset to the other.
2. if true, then remove all characters in superset indices to both schema string.
3. return true if both trimmed schema is of same string.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? What I mean efficient is in terms of execution speed / as few iterations as possible because the checker will be invoked very frequently.

Comment: "Efficient" from what perspective?

Comment: This can be done with the BitConverter I suppose..

Comment: In terms of speed. This is a part of decision tree update mechanism running on potentially infinite data stream, of which I have no control of data rate and volume.

Comment: Are you saying that the schemas can change?  Or are they fixed?  I would probably, if the schemas are fixed, 1) Remove obvious subset schemas, then 2) coalesce the existing schemas into simple wild cards (e.g 1001 and 1000 = 100*)

Comment: The context is I have a set of initial schema which represents decision tree. This Decision tree will be incrementally updated, either by growing or pruning. The update operation is inferred by new states of schema. Basically, in each increment, if the new schema is a sub-schema of one of existing schemas, the corresponding parent schema will be replaced by its children and an adjustment approximation is computed. If the new schema is super-schema of existing schemas, the sub-schemas in the list will be removed, and pruning operation will kick in.

Comment: Each wildcard `*` represents exactly one character?

Comment: yes, single character wildcard. Thus, `00**` basically means that the schema covers `{0000, 0001, 0010, 0011}`

Comment: @iOnyuman I can think of a way to speed things up maybe 10 or 100 times but I would need more context. I got the rough picture from your comments but I am not sure how your actual processing happens. Can you outline what the program as a whole is doing? What is this input stream, how do you turn it into your schemas and what are you doing with the schemas? How and when does the length of the schemas change? Ideally I would be able to implement the whole thing based on your description. Does a set of schemas represent your decision tree or are you only using them as a tool?

Comment: @DanielBrückner A tree grower algorithm constructs and incrementally updates a tree as it reads data stream. As for now, the tree is currently limited to binary tree (binary attributes, binary classes). A schema is vector path from root to leaf decision where `0`=left child, `1`=right child and `*`=not in the path. Let's say path `x2.leftChild = x3` and `x3.rightChild = label`. If there are only 5 attributes `x1 - x5`, the end schema is `*01**`. The number of attributes is set by preprocess analyzer when running the program for the first time and will be static until stream ends

Comment: Thus, a binary tree can be represented as collection of schemas and their respective outcomes. Even though the tree grows incrementally, there is currently no update mechanism of schema representation of binary tree (let's say schema tree for short). Rather than rebuilding schema tree from scratch for every update to the tree, it's better to update existing schema tree by pushing updated schemas.

Comment: The system in general can switch between using the binary tree or using Schema tree for classification. There is also an archive mechanism that will be used, so when old patterns reoccur in the stream, system will switch to use archived trees / schemas. I hope the context is quite clear for you.

Comment: My part is simply making update mechanism of schema trees and preparing them for archiving. So I only need to interface with existing system.

Comment: Alright. All the solutions provided has answered the particular problem presented. I'm marking Andrew's solution for providing various alternatives and their benchmark. Too bad that I can't vote his answer up due to my low rep. I have decided to go with safe for() solution, for now. The discussions so far are very precious because they give me an idea of several improvements in the system. Kudos to Daniel and Andrew for their precious inputs. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not *exactly* sure what you are asking, but I assume that you have a starting list of schemas that you are working off of, and that list is unique (no subsets, etc).

Define a simple `IsSubsetOf()` function, and then call that as part of a Linq 'any' call, or you can do it in a for-loop:

```
var startingSchemas = new [] { "100**101", "110*101*", "1111*000" };

startingSchemas.Any(x => IsSubsetOf(x, "11****11")); // false
startingSchemas.Any(x => IsSubsetOf(x, "11011010")); // true

public bool IsSubsetOf(string main, string sub)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < main.Length; i++)
    {
        if (main[i] == '*') continue;    // main is '*', so anything is ok
        if (main[i] == sub[i]) continue; // equal is ok, both 1/0/*
        return false; // if not equal, sub[i] could be *, or the opposite of main[i]
    }
    return true;
}
```

One issue that I think you might need to clarify is what you want to do when you find something that is NOT a subset, but when combined with another schema then it *is*.

```
1*1 => 101 or 111
0*1 => 001 or 011  (not a subset of 1*)
```

But these two combined = the `**1` schema or `{001, 011, 101, 111}`

Do you want to take a string list and then reduce it to the minimal set of schemas that will  still match the same inputs?  `IsSubset(x,y) = false`, but `IsSubset(y,x) = true`

**Addition:**
Making the starting data unique is pretty easy, if it isn't already:

```
var uniqueSchemas = startingSchemas.Distinct().ToList();
uniqueSchemas.RemoveAll(x => uniqueSchemas.Any(y => y != x && IsSubsetOf(y, x)));
```

**Compiled (release, no pdb, optimize):**

```
for (int index = 0; index < main.Length; ++index)
{
    if ((int) main[index] != 42 && (int) main[index] != (int) sub[index])
      return false;
}
```

**Performance**

Very crude performance check.  Run in parallels VM on an i7/4gb 1 core allocated to vm, other processes running, etc.

- 200 schemas (randomly generated, 800 length)
- 1 test string (800 length, randomly generated the same way)
- 1 millions runs each

Output: (*all runs were +/- 500ms at the outside, usually in unison*)

```
// unsafe = new 'public static void unsafe IsSubsetOf' function using pointers
//   safe = standard method
Any() warmup : elapsed = 11965 (.0120 ms)
Any() safe   : elapsed = 11300 (.0113 ms)
Any() unsafe : elapsed = 10754 (.0108 ms)
for() safe   : elapsed = 11480 (.0115 ms)
for() unsafe : elapsed =  7964 (.008  ms)
```

So, that what I get from this.  If there is a clever data structure for this, i've no clue.

**Unsafe Version**

This isn't guaranteed to be 100% correct.  I don't normally do this, and I don't know if the  discrepancy I saw was because of the test harness or the code.  Also, *disclaimer*, it's been a good 6 years since I wrote a tiny bit of unsafe code.  But I don't pump .net for performance this way, there is usually a bigger bottleneck...  If you do use `unsafe` code, my only advice would be to NOT modify anything.  If you just `read` you should be pretty safe.  Check all your bounds!

```
private unsafe static bool IsSubsetOfUnsafe(String main, String sub)
{
    if (main == null && sub == null) return true; // is this what you want? decide
    if (main == null || sub == null) return false; // this too? maybe if null then say "true" and discard?
    if (main.Length != sub.Length) return false;

    fixed (char* m = main)
    fixed (char* s = sub)
    {
        var m1 = m;
        var s1 = s;
        int len = main.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if ((int)m1 != 42 && m1 != s1) return false;
            m1++;
            s1++;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to quickly check if one schema is a subset of another. Schema string can be quite long, e.g. 800 character long is common, and the check can run thousands times in matter of seconds (not minutes, really. Can't edit my comment so I had to remove and re-add). That's why I'm reluctant to use the scan-each-character approach.

Comment: Well, you can certainly hide that under some abstraction, but in the end that is still what it is doing, correct?  Is there a way to check that a string is a match (in this manner) without checking characters? Sure, but you can't permute all the possibilities (800^2!). This way at least checks the fewest chars possible... the only thing I can see to speed it up is to use `unsafe{}` and do checks with raw pointers

Comment: @iOnyuman If a schema is a subschema you *have to* compare all symbols to verify this, no way around that. (Small lie - sometimes it is enough to look only at one of the symbols beeing compared.) Only if a schema is not a subschema you can stop as soon as you found the first incompatible difference. so you can only beat comparing all symbols if you have additional information about the input, i.e. the distribution of inputs. Can you provide such information?

Comment: How are the lengths of the schemas distributed? How many wildcards are in the schema and the schema candidates? How are they distributed? How large is the set of subschema candidates? How many subschema candidates are actually subschemas? How are mismatches between the schema and the schema candidates distributed? I can think of a few optimizations that might speed the thing up but they heavily depend on the inputs.

Comment: The only thing I can think that *might* make it fast (depending on distribution) is to walk through all the schemas for each character until you fail.  If there are a lot of schemas, the chance that any one has a matching at position `x` is high.  Also, you end up creating and maintaing all sorts of temporaries.  At least this way you allocate no new storage (e.g `x schemas` matched `position y`, now check `y+1`, and so on.

Comment: To clarify, initial schema set is guaranteed to be unique. In a decision tree, a split attribute can't be a descendant node of itself, be it direct child or sub-child. The set of update schema is of arbitrary length, because I'm building a decision tree on data streams. So the tree is _constantly_ being updated, either by addition of new nodes, which will split one of the initial schema into exactly 2 subschemas, or by collapsing of splitting node, which combines a couple of schemas in the initial schema.

Comment: The list, or queue to be precise, of update schemas represents chronological and incremental update of the decision tree. Thus it may contain either subschema / parentschema of initial schemas OR subschema / parentschema of earlier update schemas.

Comment: @AndrewBacker I'm interested in using unsafe. May I see a snippet of your code using pointer? My programming background is Java, without any experience in C/C++.

Comment: @iOnyuman, sorry, i don't live in the u.s. anymore, so a little time difference here.  tonight was our pool tournament :D

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly this should do what you want and it performs as little work as possible assuming mismatching positions are unbiased. It might however be faster not to use LINQ. If you need the resulting list only once you can probably get away without turning the result into a list.

```
var s = "0*10*";

var sscs = new[] { "11010", "0010*", "0*11*", "1*100" };

var sss = sscs.Where(ssc => s.Zip(ssc, (a, b) => (a == b) || (a == '*')).All(_ => _)).ToList();
```

Every subschema candidate is compared symbol by symbol with the specified schema. If all symbols match or the schema has a wildcard in case of an mismatch the subschema candidate is a subschema. The comparison is aborted immediately if there is a mismatch and schema has no wildcard.

I heavily abbreviated the variable names to make it (almost) fit.

```
s     schema
sscs  subschema candidates
ssc   subschema candidate
sss   subschemas
a     symbol in schema
b     symbol in subschema candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I still don't fully understand what you are doing but I will present my idea anyway, maybe it is useful.

The central idea is to replace your string representation with a more compact bit representation - your string `1*10` for example gets turned into `11001110` or `0xCE`. Because one symbol takes up 2 bits you can pack 32 symbols into one `UInt64`, longer strings become arrays of `UInt64`s.

```
0 => 10
1 => 11
* => 00
     01 => unused
```

Now you can find subschemas with the following LINQ expression

```
var sss = sscs.Where(ssc => s.Zip(ssc, (a, b) => (a ^ b) & ((a & 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) | ((a & 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) >> 1))).All(x => x == 0)).ToList();
```

that is structure like my previous answer to make the comparison more meaningful. The obvious advantage is that it processes 32 symbols in parallel and indeed it is 30 times faster than my previous answer. But I am actually a bit disappointed because I hopped for maybe a 100 times speedup because the compacter representation also means less memory traffic but maybe the overhead from using LINQ is the actual bottleneck. So I turned it into plain `for` loops and this made it 130 times faster than the LINQ string version. But this is only really useful if it can be deeply integrated into your application because the conversion between the string representation and this representation is quite expensive.